# Console ./a.out not working

Tags: c++, linux, bash, gsl

I'm trying to compile a simple program in c++ with gsl. On our university server we have installed GSL. The main problem is, that I'm compilling:

```
g++ atest.cpp -c -lgsl -lgslcblas -c lm
```

And after that, I'm typing:

```
./a.out
```

And I get :

```
-bash: ./a.out : No such file or directory
```

What's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that compile succeeded *and* generated an actual `a.out` file? You're asking for `atest.o` with the `-c` flag.

Comment: Do you understand the command line arguments that you gave to `g++`?  Why did you use `-c`?  Remove that argument.

Comment: Why are you using `-c`?

Comment: have you checked if the executable has been generated ?, check with `ls`

Comment: Ok, deleting -c flag helped. Thanks!

Comment: a simple `ls` would have shown you that the file doesn't actually exist

Answer (score 7):

You're only compiling, not linking.  From `man gcc`:

```
       -c  Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking
           stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form of an
           object file for each source file.

           By default, the object file name for a source file is made by
           replacing the suffix .c, .i, .s, etc., with .o.

           Unrecognized input files, not requiring compilation or assembly,
           are ignored.
```

Comment: Useful supplemental reading: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Answer (score 2):

So `-c` option (command line argument) means compile

```
g++ atest.cpp -c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
g++ atest.o
```

this will produce `a.out` file, or you can use short hand

```
g++ atest.cpp -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

which will compile and link code in one.

Plus, you could use `ls` to check your directory does it contain `a.out` before trying to run it.